# How do I write xaml to bind (in MAUI) to a field other than the one specified in ItemsSource of the CollectionView?

Tags: xaml, maui, model-binding

I have this (probably naïve question):

I have this xaml:

```
<CollectionView
    ItemsSource="{Binding Receipts}"
    SelectionMode="None">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Receipt">
            <Grid Padding="1, 1, 1, 1">

                <Frame Style="{StaticResource CardView}">
                    <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer
                            Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodel:ER_Expense_Receipts_View_VM}}, Path=GoToReceiptDetailsCommand}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
                    </Frame.GestureRecognizers>

                    <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto, *" ColumnDefinitions="310, 20" RowSpacing="10">
                        <Image
                            x:Name="imgReceipt"
                            Aspect="AspectFit"
                            Margin="0"
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                            Source="{Binding ContentsThumbnail, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource ByteArrayToImageSourceConverter}}"
                            WidthRequest="300" />

                        <Label
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            FontSize="12"
                            HorizontalOptions="Center"
                            HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                            VerticalOptions="Start"
                            VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                            HeightRequest="30"
                            Text="{Binding Description}">
                        </Label>

                        <ImageButton
                            x:Name="cmdDelete"
                            Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodel:ER_Expense_Receipts_View_VM}}, Path=DeleteReceiptCommand}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding ID}"
                            Grid.Row="1"
                            Grid.Column="1"
                            Source="delete2.svg"
                            HeightRequest="20"
                            WidthRequest="40">
                            <ImageButton.Triggers>                                            
                                <DataTrigger TargetType="ImageButton" Binding="{Binding ExpenseReport.Status}" Value="{x:Static res:AppRes.StatusSent}">
                                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                                    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="Gray" />
                                </DataTrigger>                                            
                            </ImageButton.Triggers>

                        </ImageButton>
                    </Grid>
                </Frame>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

Receipts is a collection of Receipt objects in my "ER_Expense_Receipts_View_VM" model:

```
[ObservableProperty]
private Receipt receipt;

public ObservableCollection<Receipt> Receipts { get; } = new();
```

Also in my model I have this property

```
[ObservableProperty]
private Expense expense;
```

What I need to do here is to bind the "cmdDelete" ImageButton's property IsEnabled to the Status field of the ExpenseReport object in the model. See below. Alas, I get the message "Member not found in data context 'Receipt'".

So, please, what I am doing wrong here ? What's the correct syntax to bind that IsEnabled property to some field in the model other than from the Receipt objects ?

Thank you very much,

Alex

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/data-binding/relative-bindings?view=net-maui-7.0

Comment: Thank you, Jason :-) Sorry for my stupid question - I had missed reading that page.  Problem solved !

Comment: @Alex you can answer your own question if you found the answer